# Is Haskell's type system formally equivalent to Java's?

Tags: java, haskell, type-systems, static-typing

I realize some things are easier/harder in one language than the other, but I'm only interested in type-related features that are possible in one and impossible/irrelevant in the other.  To make it more specific, let's ignore Haskell type extensions since there's so many out there that do all kinds of crazy/cool stuff.

Comment: I too am curious to hear the long winded category theorists answer to this question; though I doubt I will particularly understand it, I am still interested in a detailing of this. My inclination from things I've read is that the HM type system allows the compiler to know a *ton* about what your code does which is why it is capable of inferring types so much as well as giving so many guarantees about the behavior. But that's just my gut instinct and I'm sure there are other things to it which I'm utterly unaware of.

Comment: The most important difference I believe is list manipulation.

Comment: This is a great question - time to tweet it out to followers for the great Haskell/JVM debate!

Comment: @Matt Fenwick Being a functional language Haskell has built in support for higher-order functions; you can easily apply map or reduce over a list in Haskell for example. Of course the same functionality can be provided with Java also, but not directly.

Comment: @m3th0dman: Scala has the exact same support for higher-order functions as Java has. In Scala, first-class functions are simply represented as instances of abstract classes with a single abstract method, just like Java. Sure, Scala has syntactic sugar for defining these functions, and it has a rich standard library of both pre-defined function types and methods that accept functions, but from a *type system perspective*, which is what this question is about, there is no difference. So, if Scala can do it, then Java can, too, and in fact there are Haskell-inspired FP libraries for Java.

Comment: @m3th0dman: That's not what this question is about.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag What I was trying to say is that Haskell has built in support for lists; they are special types while in Java are just ordinary objects.

Comment: @m3th0dman They're perfectly ordinary types. There's nothing special about lists except some synactic niceties. You can easily define your own algebraic data type that's equivalent to the built-in list type except for the literal syntax and the names of the constructors.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

("Java", as used here, is defined as [standard Java SE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html); "Haskell", as used here, is defined as [standard Haskell 2010](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/).)

Things that Java's type system has but that Haskell's doesn't:

- nominal subtype polymorphism
- partial runtime type information

Things that Haskell's type system has but that Java's doesn't:

- bounded ad-hoc polymorphism

  - gives rise to "constraint-based" subtype polymorphism
- higher-kinded parametric polymorphism
- principal typing

---

**EDIT:**

Examples of each of the points listed above:

## Unique to Java (as compared to Haskell)

### Nominal subtype polymorphism

```java
/* declare explicit subtypes (limited multiple inheritance is allowed) */
abstract class MyList extends AbstractList<String> implements RandomAccess {

    /* specify a type's additional initialization requirements */
    public MyList(elem1: String) {
        super() /* explicit call to a supertype's implementation */
        this.add(elem1) /* might be overridden in a subtype of this type */
    }

}

/* use a type as one of its supertypes (implicit upcasting) */
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>() /* some inference is available for generics */
```

### Partial runtime type information

```java
/* find the outermost actual type of a value at runtime */
Class<?> c = l.getClass // will be 'java.util.ArrayList'

/* query the relationship between runtime and compile-time types */
Boolean b = l instanceOf MyList // will be 'false'
```

## Unique to Haskell (as compared to Java)

### Bounded ad-hoc polymorphism

```
-- declare a parametrized bound
class A t where
  -- provide a function via this bound
  tInt :: t Int
  -- require other bounds within the functions provided by this bound
  mtInt :: Monad m => m (t Int)
  mtInt = return tInt -- define bound-provided functions via other bound-provided functions

-- fullfill a bound
instance A Maybe where
  tInt = Just 5
  mtInt = return Nothing -- override defaults

-- require exactly the bounds you need (ideally)
tString :: (Functor t, A t) => t String
tString = fmap show tInt -- use bounds that are implied by a concrete type (e.g., "Show Int")
```

#### "Constraint-based" subtype polymorphism (based on bounded ad-hoc polymorphism)

```
-- declare that a bound implies other bounds (introduce a subbound)
class (A t, Applicative t) => B t where -- bounds don't have to provide functions

-- use multiple bounds (intersection types in the context, union types in the full type)
mtString :: (Monad m, B t) => m (t String)
mtString = return mtInt -- use a bound that is implied by another bound (implicit upcasting)

optString :: Maybe String
optString = join mtString -- full types are contravariant in their contexts
```

### Higher-kinded parametric polymorphism

```
-- parametrize types over type variables that are themselves parametrized
data OneOrTwoTs t x = OneVariableT (t x) | TwoFixedTs (t Int) (t String)

-- bounds can be higher-kinded, too
class MonadStrip s where
  -- use arbitrarily nested higher-kinded type variables
  strip :: (Monad m, MonadTrans t) => s t m a -> t m a -> m a
```

### Principal typing

This one is difficult to give a direct example of, but it means that every expression has exactly one maximally general type (called its *principal type*), which is considered the canonical type of that expression.  In terms of "constraint-based" subtype polymorphism (see above), the principal type of an expression is the unique subtype of every possible type that that expression can be used as.  The presence of principal typing in (unextended) Haskell is what allows complete type inference (that is, successful type inference for every expression, without any type annotations needed).  Extensions that break principal typing (of which there are many) also break the completeness of type inference.

Comment: Don't use `l` as a single letter variable, it is ***VERY*** difficult to distinguish from `1`!

Comment: It may be worth noting, that while you are absolutely right that Java has some runtime type information and Haskell does not, you can use the Typeable type-class in Haskell to provide something which behaves like runtime type information for many types (with newer PolyKinded classes on the way, it will be all types iirc), although I think it depends on the situation whether it actually passes any type information at runtime or not.

Comment: @DarkOtter I'm aware of `Typeable`, but Haskell 2010 does not have it (maybe Haskell 2014 will?).

Comment: What about (closed) sum types? They're one of the more important mechanisms for encoding constraints.

Comment: Nullability? Soundness (no covariance sillinses)? Closed sum types/pattern matches? This answer is way too narrow

Comment: @Peaker To defend Ptharien's Flame a bit: pattern matches and nullability don't really seem like core type system features (they can be added on or removed from either Haskell or Java without changing too much), and no covariance silliness comes from subtyping (which he mentioned Haskell does not have).

Comment: @DanielWagner He asked what Haskell's type system can do that Java can't, not what are "core"/difficult to add features.  Haskell can detect null dereferences at compile-time, Java can't. This is a *major* feature, and worth emphasizing more than others.
By "covariance silliness" I don't mean subtyping. I mean Java having the *wrong* covariance for arrays and breaking Java's type system's soundness.

Comment: I would have mentioned Haskell's powerful type inference...

Comment: @ErikAllik he did mention the powerful type inference in the 'Principal typing' section.

Answer (score 32):

Java's type system lacks higher kinded polymorphism; Haskell's type system has it.

In other words: in Java, type constructors can abstract over types, but not over type constructors, whereas in Haskell, type constructors can abstract over type constructors as well as types.

In English: in Java a generic can't take in another generic type and parameterize it,

```
public void <Foo> nonsense(Foo<Integer> i, Foo<String> j)
```

while in Haskell this is quite easy

```
higherKinded :: Functor f => f Int -> f String
higherKinded = fmap show
```

Comment: Mind running that by us again, in English this time? :P

Comment: @MasonWheeler: you can't pass a generic to a generic. If `A` and `B` are both generic, you can't say `A<B>`. (Well, actually, that's syntactically valid, but it means something totally different: `B` here is the *raw type*, so, this is equivalent to `A<B<java.lang.Object>>`)

Comment: Interesting ... I'm not quite sure I grasp it completely though; could you add a short code sample?

Comment: What we're talking about is parameterized types, or Generics in Java-speak. `Foo<T>` is actually a method (called a type constructor) `Foo(Type T) => Type`. Java requires the parameter to be a type and only a type. Haskell allows other type constructors as parameters: `Bar(Type -> Type T) => Type`. This allows Haskell to take another unparameterized generic (ie `List` or `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`) as a generic parameter, since they're technically methods with the signature `f(Type) => Type`.

Comment: @Matt: As an example I can't write this in Java, but I can write the equivalent in Haskell: `<T<_> extends Collection> T<Integer> convertStringsToInts(T<string> strings)`. The idea here would be that if someone called it as `convertStringsToInts<ArrayList>` it would take an arraylist of strings and return an arraylist of integers. And if they instead used `convertStringsToInts<LinkedList>`, it'd be the same with linked lists instead.

Comment: Isn't this higher-kinded polymorphism, rather than rank 1 vs n?

Comment: @Adam: I thought higher-kinded polymorphism was a synonym for higher-rank polymorphism, i.e. polymorphism of rank > 1. Feel free to edit the answer if I was wrong.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: My understanding is that higher-rank polymorphism concerns where you can put the `forall` in your types. In Haskell, a type `a -> b` is implicitly `forall a. forall b. a -> b`. With an extension, you can make these `forall`s explicit and move them around.

Comment: @Adam is rigtht: higher rank and higher kinded are totally different. GHC can also do higher ranked types (i.e. forall types) with some language extension. Java knows neither higher kinded nor higher ranked types.

Comment: Higher-rank ( http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Rank-N_types ) /= higher-kinds ( http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Kind )

Comment: @Ingo Java actually can do what GHC calls `PolymorphicComponents`, which is a restricted form of rank-2 polymorphism and is sufficient to emulate full higher-rank polymorphism with full type safety (module how type-safe Java is to begin with, of course).

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame you make interesting claims. Can you substantiate them?

Comment: @Ingo Sure.  See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3916060) for an explanation/demonstration.

Comment: `s/module/modulo/g` in my twice-previous comment.

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame I see. I think I understand the idea. But I think you agree that this is merely of academic interest - by analogy, one can simulate OO features in C, yet nobody claims that C's type system has subtyping.

Comment: @Ingo On the contrary:  C's does not have subtyping only because everything ends up as `void *` when simulating OO; Java's generics are fully compile-time checked, so its type system has exactly as much support for higher-rank polymorphism as it it does for functions in the first place, i.e., it can be ***safely*** simulated.  "Safely" is the key word here, as C's type system does not enforce the simulated subtyping, whereas Java's **does** enforce the simulated `PolymorphicComponents`.

Comment: @Ingo (cont.) Whether or not anyone besides us academic types actually takes advantage of it, though, is another matter entirely.  ;)

Answer (score 11):

To complement the other answers, Haskell's type system doesn't have [subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype), while typed object oriented languages as Java do.

> In [programming language theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_theory), **subtyping** (also **subtype polymorphism** or **inclusion polymorphism**) is a form of [type polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) in which a **subtype** is a [datatype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datatype) that is related to another datatype (the **supertype**) by some notion of [substitutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), meaning that program elements, typically subroutines or functions, written to operate on elements of the supertype can also operate on elements of the subtype. If S is a subtype of T, the subtyping relation is often written S <: T, to mean that any term of type S can be *safely used in a context where* a term of type T is expected. The precise semantics of subtyping crucially depends on the particulars of what "safely used in a context where" means in a given programming language. The [type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) of a programming language essentially defines its own subtyping relation, which may well be trivial.
>
> Due to the subtyping relation, a term may belong to more than one type. Subtyping is therefore a form of type polymorphism. In object-oriented programming the term 'polymorphism' is commonly used to refer solely to this *subtype polymorphism*, while the techniques of parametric polymorphism would be considered [*generic programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming)...

Comment: Though that does not mean you don't get ad-hoc polymorphism. You do, just in a different form (type classes instead of subtype polymorphism).

Comment: Subclassing is not subtyping!

Answer (score 8):

One thing nobody's mentioned so far is type inference: a Haskell compiler can usually infer the type of expressions but you have to tell the Java compiler your types in detail. Strictly, this is a feature of the compiler but the design of the language and type system determines whether type inference is feasible. In particular, type inference interacts badly with Java's subtype polymorphism and ad hoc overloading. In contrast, the designers of Haskell try hard not to introduce features that impact type inference.

Another thing people don't seem to have mentioned so far is algebraic data types. That is, the ability to construct types from sums ('or') and products ('and') of other types. Java classes do products (field a and field b, say) fine. But they don't really do sums (field a OR field b, say). Scala has to encode this as multiple case classes, which isn't quite the same. And while it works for Scala it's a bit of a stretch to say Java has it.

Haskell can also construct function types using the function constructor, ->. While Java's methods do have type signatures, you can't combine them.

Java's type system does enable a type of *modularity* that Haskell hasn't got. It will be a while before there's an OSGi for Haskell.

Comment: @MattFenwick, I modified the 3rd paragraph based on your feedback. The two type systems do treat functions very differently.

Comment: I wouldn't call ADTs a feature of the type system. You can fully (if awkwardly) emulate them with OO wrappers.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think this is arguably. For example, there could be things which are native to a type system of one language, but could be implemented with design patterns in another one. Obviously, the design pattern way, in comparison to a native one, is a workaround. The workaround due to a weaker type system.

Comment: The chosen answer mentioned 'complete type inference' in the 'Principal typing' section. Java can sort of emulate sums with subtypes and runtime type information, but as you say it is not the same as the sum isn't a holistic attribute of the type system.